# how to get the text in shell between two specific character ( [ ] bracket ) with sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

i try to get the text in shell between two specific character with sed, in shell, but it doesnt seem to work.

i try to get text from "[" and "]"

```
[561:0:43:0] ->  561:0:43:0
```

so i tried as follow

```
sed -e '/[/,/]/p' test > test2
```

test content is for example:

```
[561:0:42:0]
[561:0:43:0] 
[561:0:478:0]
[561:0:48:0] 
[562:0:9:0]
```

after the command when i read test2 its still the contains the brackets

i tried to search some alternatives here, but cant find aníthing to work.

any suggestion ?
thanks

Comment: Are those the entirety of the lines you are dealing with in this case? Because for that there are any number of solutions `cat test | tr -d []`, `sed -e s'/\[\]//' test`, etc. But if the lines are more complicated a more complicated solution is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt get the expected output becuase

- `p` command prints the entire pattern space,( or in your sed command the current line read)

You can use something like

```
$ sed -r 's/\[(.*)\]/\1/g' test
561:0:42:0
561:0:43:0
561:0:478:0
561:0:48:0
562:0:9:0
```

- `s` commands substitutes anything within `[]` with the contents of `\1` capture group 1, caputured by the `(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9:]*' <<< "[561:0:43:0]"
561:0:43:0

$ tr -d '[]' <<< "[561:0:43:0]"
561:0:43:0

$ awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}' <<< "[561:0:43:0]"
561:0:43:0

$ echo "[561:0:43:0]" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1
561:0:43:0
```

bash:

```
$ STR="[561:0:43:0]"
$ STR=${STR#*[}
$ STR=${STR%]*}
$ echo $STR
561:0:43:0
```

and finally some perl:

```
$ perl -l -ne '/\[([0-9:]*)\]/ and print $1' <<< "[561:0:43:0]"
561:0:43:0
```

Answer (score 0):

If input lines has more than just your `[...]` token, than I'd suggest nu11p01n73R's answer. If your goal is only to get rid of `[`and `]`, the simplest answer would be :

```
sed 's/[][]//g' test > test2
```

Proof :

```
$ sed 's/[][]//g' <<EOF
> [561:0:42:0]
> [561:0:43:0] 
> [561:0:478:0]
> [561:0:48:0] 
> [562:0:9:0]
> EOF
561:0:42:0
561:0:43:0 
561:0:478:0
561:0:48:0 
562:0:9:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
sed -r 's/(\[)(.*)(\])/\2/g'
```